# Can we have two setters in a pojo?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have a setter that converts a string to byte[] and one simple setter which just sets the value. My question here is, is it a good practice to have two setters in a POJO? I can't find any workaround :(

**Example:**

```
byte[] a;

//Case 1: Where we recieve parameter as a string and convert it to byte array and set it to a; 
public void setA(String aString){
this.a=convertTobyteArray(aString);
}

//Case 2: Where we receive parameter as a byte array where conversion is not required and we directly assign it to a
public void setA(byte[] a){
this.a=a;
}
```

Comment: @YassirKhaldi syntactically, sure. But the question is about whether this breaks the POJO abstraction, not whether Java allows it.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller It's done.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it compiles so literally you can! :-) Anyway it's probably not the answer you want to hear. From the two methods, only `setA(byte[])` is setter in the meaning as was coined by JavaBeans specification. The other method is just helper method with name starting with `set`. I think your code is ok in most cases. Some problem could arise if some reflection-based tool scanned the methods (rather than fields because they are public) and tried to guess the field type from method parameter type - it would be confused then.

Also I would also consider to reimplement helper method as:

```
public void setA(String aString){
    setA(convertTobyteArray(aString));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A setter is simply a `public void` method that changes the value of an encapsulated field, and in Java you can add as much methods as you want with the same name and different signatures thanks to **method overloading**.

So the answer is YES you can have multiple setters with different parameters and it's not considered a bad practice.